# Difference between official Apple code and code provided here

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I just want to ask what is the difference between official update function in SpriteKit provided by Apple and update function provided by raywenderlich. Why should I use self.lastUpdate time rather than normal variable? Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
private var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval = 0
private var dt: TimeInterval = 0
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval){
    if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    }
    else {
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    print("\(dt * 1000) in miliseconds since last update")
}}
```

And here is official function

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
private var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

    // Initialize _lastUpdateTime if it has not already been
    if (self.lastUpdateTime == 0) {
        self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    }

    // Calculate time since last update
    let dt = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTime

    // Update entities
    for entity in self.entities {
        entity.update(deltaTime: dt)
    }

    self.lastUpdateTime = currentTime
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean what is the difference between `self.lastUpdateTime` and `lastUpdateTime`? If so, there is technically none - just a matter of convention/style.

Comment: Yeah, just difference between self.lastUpdateTime

Comment: Thank you so much for very fast answer

Comment: would you need a _mathematical_ explanation? or would you expect a _performance_ analysis between the two solutions? or what would you actually like to know actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation you are using it, there is no difference between `self.lastUpdateTime` and `lastUpdateTime`. It's a matter of personal preference.

There are a couple of situations where you do need to differentiate:

- if a parameter is shadowing a property. This most commonly occurs in initialisers e.g.

  ```
  class Foo 
  {
      var property: Int
      init(property: Int)
      {
          self.property = property
      }
  }
  ```
- Self is mandatory in closures as a prompt to remind you about possible strong reference cycles.

  ```
  class Foo
  {
      var property: Int = 1
      func bar()
      {
          DispatchQueue.main.async
          {
              print("\(self.property)") // self required here
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Other than that, use `self` or don't use `self` however you like. In the early days of Swift evolution, it was proposed to make `self` mandatory for property access. The fight was long and bitter but in the end the non mandatory side won the argument, so knock yourself out.